# need to add a word to a div if a certain object value is true

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I'm parsing some data from a webservice here. 
I'm just throwing in a bunch of values from a json object into html, however! i need to check if a certain json value is set to true or false. If so, i need to remove/add a word.

So i basicly i need to get a bunch of prices out. That's easy

```
    $.each(data.d, function (i, service) {
            $(".services").append('<li class="classes here"><p class="servicePrice">'+service.Price+' kr</p><div class="serviceNames">' + service.Name +'<br />' + service.FirstAvailableSlot + '</div>

});
```

Now! i have to check for this value called FromPrice in the JSON object. And if that is true, then the word 'fra' should be added to the beginning of the the p tag with the class servicePrice.

Now, i certainly can't do it like this.

```
$.each(data.d, function (i, service) {
                if (service.PriceFrom == false) { $('.servicePrice').prepend('fra '); };
                $(".services").append('<li class="classes here"><p class="servicePrice">'+service.Price+' kr</p><div class="serviceNames">' + service.Name +'<br />' + service.FirstAvailableSlot + '</div>

    });
```

That's just gonna add the word a whole bunch of times depending on how many loops we go through.

i've tried doing it the whole if thing inside the servicePrice tag. But that just gave me a whole lot of javascript parse errors.

Anyone wanna throw this guy a bone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** I'm still not sure about this, but is this what you're looking for?

```
$.each(data.d, function (i, service) {
    var txt = (service.PriceFrom == false) ? "fra" : "";
    $(".services").append('<li class="classes here">'+txt+'<p class="servicePrice">'+service.Price+' kr</p><div class="serviceNames">' + service.Name +'<br />' + service.FirstAvailableSlot + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do the trick unfortunately , it adds the 'fra ' but not in relation to what it should. if i look through the json object i get when i call the webservice, and crosscheck it with the 'list' of results. Some of these rows should not have the word 'Fra ', and yet every single one of them did. With one exception, the last one.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! And utterly ashamed that i didn't think of this myself. Thanks for the help @Mrchief!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then this should work.

```
var isFalse = false;
    $.each(data.d, function (i, service) {
            if (service.PriceFrom == false && !isFalse) { 
                $('.servicePrice').prepend('fra ');
                isFalse = true;
            };
            $(".services").append('<li class="classes here"><p class="servicePrice">'+service.Price+' kr</p><div class="serviceNames">' + service.Name +'<br />' + service.FirstAvailableSlot + '</div>

});
```